# Calculating max and min pixel values for numerous overlaying rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, raster-calculator, spatial-statistics

I have over 1000 interpolated raster layers. I'm trying to use QGIS 3.16 to create a confidence interval map by finding the difference between the highest and lowest values at each pixel and creating a new raster layer showing these calculated differences. They are all the same cell size and are all aligned already, I'm just trying to create the calculated surface. I'm not much of a coder.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Minimum raster of all the layers >  Create a Maximum raster of all the layers >
Create a Difference raster of the 2 MIN and MAX Rasters.

1. Create a raster of **MINIMUM pixel values** for each cell:

   **Mosaic raster Layers** tool:
   For Input Grids: '**Add Directory**' choose the location of your 1000 files
   For 'Overlapping Layers' Choose:  '**[2] minimum**'
   [image]
2. Create a raster of **MAXIMUM pixel values** for each cell:
   **Mosaic raster Layers** tool:
   For Input Grids: '**Add Directory**' choose the location of your 1000 files
   For 'Overlapping Layers' Choose:  '**[3] maximum**'
   [image]
3. Create the **RASTER DIFFERENCE** layer:
   **Raster Difference** tool:
   A: '**Maximum Raster Values**
   B: '**Minimum Raster Values**
   [image]